# bootstrap align element on one separate line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Simple question how to get this rendering (see img)? using bootstrap, I tried but I can't.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
        <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
        <div class="ml-auto p-2">Flex item</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: You have CSS tagged in this post, but do not provide any. Can you please add your CSS

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to insert it in a row, or a container. The d-flex div is already a row. This works just as you pictured

```css
.d-flex div {
background-color: red;
outline: 1px solid black;
}

.d-flex {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
  <div class="ml-auto p-2">Flex item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: IF this helped you don't forget to accept :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.p-2 {
  width:100px;
}

.d-flex-r {
  flex-direction: row; 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex">
       <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
       <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex-r">
    <div class="ml-auto p-2">Flex item</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you can use bootstrap 5:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex bd-highlight mb-3">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    <div class="ms-auto p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`d-flex justify-content-between`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/)

```css
.item-container,
.item {
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .15)
}

.item {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between item-container">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="item">Flex item</div>
    <div class="item">Flex item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">Flex item</div>
</div>
```